# strokeWidth not working for path-group

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to add strokeWidth for imported path-group type objects in fabricjs, but it is not working though if i view in console the updated strokeWdith exist. Here is my code

```
canvas.getObjects()[x].strokeWidth += 11.34;
canvas.renderAll();
```

Any help please?

Comment: Check this example (select "Text example" and click in "strokeWidth" button): http://jsfiddle.net/68fDR/

Comment: not this, i mean path-group type objects, that is complex objects..

Answer (score 0):

as far I understand, it is not possible to add strokeWidth to complex (path-group) type object, as there are so many different shapes that develops that complex object. Adding strokeWidth will make the shape/object broken pieces.